# Expectation of inverse of sum of iid random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, inverse, distribution-tails

**Description:**

There is an indicator function called $I_{i}^{k}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
 \begin{split}
 I_{i}^{k}= \left\{
 \begin{array}{lr}
 1, \; {\rm if \; the  \; event \;  happened\; at\; time \;k\; for\; player\; i;}\\
 0, \; {\rm if  \; not.}
 \end{array}
 \right.
 \end{split}  
 \end{align*}
The event happened at least once, so $\mathbb{E}[I_{i}^{k}]=p_{i}>0$.  Besides,  the indicators
$I_{i}^{k}, \left\lbrace i=1,\dots N \right\rbrace $  are independent and
identically distributed (i.i.d.) with a fixed distribution across
time steps.

Now, we Let $\Gamma_{i}^{k}=\sum_{t=1}^{k}I_{i}^{t}$ and $\gamma_{i,k}={1}/{(\Gamma_{i}^{k})^{a}}$, $a\in (1/2, 1]$
for all $i$ and $k\geq 1$.

**Can we give the upper bound of the following?**

\begin{align*}
(a) \sum_{k=1}^{K}\mathbb{E}\left[ \gamma_{i,k}^{2}\right] \leq ?   \quad\quad  
(b) \sum_{k=1}^{K}\mathbb{E}\left[ \left| 
\gamma_{i,k}-\frac{1}{k^{a}p_{i}^{a}} \right| \right] 
\leq ?
\end{align*}
where $K$ is some constant.

**PS:** I think maybe it can be proved by `Taylor expansion`, but I don't know how to calculate it, maybe the following link is useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399261/expectation-of-inverse-of-sum-of-positive-iid-variables/399289#399289

Comment: pls note that $\mathsf{P}(\Gamma_i^k=0)=(1-p_i)^k>0$, $\mathsf{E}[\gamma_{i,k}]=\infty$.

Comment: Hi,  JGWang~ Thank you so much for your tips. Maybe I didn’t make it clear that the `event` occurs at least once, so the indicator function’s expectation is equal to $p_i$, and $p_i$ is greater than $0$. So $\Gamma_{i}^{k}$ will not be equal to $0$, that is, $P(\Gamma_{i}^{k}=0)=0$. How to prove the upper bound has troubled me for a long time.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your notation $\Gamma_i^k$. Now, I have following question:
what is the relationship between $\{I_i^1, I_i^2,\cdots,I_i^t\}$, independent or dependent?
(Is $\Gamma_i^k =\sum_{t=1}^{k}I_i^t$ a independent sum?)

Comment: Yes~$\{I_{i}^{1}, I_{i}^{2}, ... , I_{i}^{k}\}$ are independent, so the sum $\Gamma_{i}^{k}=\sum_{t=1}^{k}I_{i}^{t}$ is a independent sum.

Comment: Thank you for your replication.  Due to the $\Gamma_i^k =\sum_{t=1}^{k}I_i^t$ is a independent sum,
then $\mathsf{P}(\Gamma_i^k=0) = \mathsf{P}(\bigcap_{1\le t\le k}\{I^t_i=0\}) = (1-p_i)^k>0$.